# SQL Query to show 3 user names from userID's in one Bug record

Tags: sql, ms-access, select, join

I would like to show all the usernames who have interacted with a bug in MS Access. I do not understand how to reference the same Users.UserName field 3 times in my select statement?

Here are my tables

```
--------------------------------------------
Table 'Bugs'
--------------------------------------------
BugID    OpendBy    ClosedBy    LastChangedBy
1           1          3               2    
2           3          4               4           
3           2          4               4
4           3          1               3

--------------------------------------------
Table 'Users'
--------------------------------------------
ID    UserName        
1     Joe      
2     Chris   
3     Steve     
4     Sarah
```

I would like the query to return

```
BugID OpendBy ClosedBy LastChangedBy 
1       Joe     Steve     Chris
2       Steve   Sarah     Sarah
3       Chris   Sarah     Sarah
4       Steve   Joe       Steve
```

Comment: You do it with three joins to the Users table, using different aliases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` below for `ClosedBy`, as I assume this value can be `NULL`. If anyof the others can be `NULL`, you'll need to change those joins to `LEFT OUTER` as well.

```
select b.BugID, uo.UserName as OpendBy, 
    uc.UserName as ClosedBy, 
    ul.LastName as LastChangedBy
from Bugs b
inner join Users uo on b.OpendBy = uo.ID
left outer join Users uc on b.ClosedBy = uc.ID
inner join Users ul on b.LastChangedBy = ul.ID
```

Comment: Beat me to it. I've deleted my answer.

Comment: select b.BugID, uo.UserName as OpendBy, 
uc.UserName as ClosedBy, 
ul.UserName as LastChangedBy
FROM (((Bugs b
inner join Users uo on b.OpendBy = uo.ID)
left outer join Users uc on b.ClosedBy = uc.ID)
inner join Users ul on b.LastChangedBy = ul.ID)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid all the ugly joining, you could structure this instead as a separate table with BugID, ActionType (OpenedBy, ClosedBy, LastChangedBy) and UserID. Then you could also have a date field, instead of having three different date fields in your but record.

Records are cheap, fields are expensive.